# Netty client connections are getting ReadTimeout

Tags: netty

We have a server which accept connection from remote agents and collect the data. The server was designed to handle more connections.We are having a problem rarely remote client connections are getting disconnected. ( Server is disconnecting the client because of READER is IDLE for 3 min ). There won't be case of reader idle because client is sending the heart beat message for every 1 min.

This is happening only when all the connections ( 2500 ) connection are trying to send some xml file to the server at the almost same time. The movement it triggered after 3 min server is getting events from the netty few of the connections are READ IDLE.

At that movement i took the thread dump what is causing the issue i could see all the netty worker threads are in Runnable state with the following thread state.

```
nioEventLoopGroup-18-98" #1366 prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f5d2088c000 nid=0x3572 runnable [0x00007f5c0386b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
    - locked <0x0000000508768610> (a io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySet)
    - locked <0x0000000508768688> (a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableSet)
    - locked <0x000000050721baa0> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:97)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.select(SelectedSelectionKeySetSelector.java:62)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:753)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:409)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Once 30-50 connections droped by server then it comes to normal state.

What could be the problem?

I Increased the timeout from 3 min 5 min. Now i am not receiving the read timeouts but connection is getting disconnected silently.

```
StackTrace
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
com......
com......
com......
com......
com......
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:181)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:167)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:160)
io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:181)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:167)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:160)
io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelUnregistered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:53)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:181)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:167)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:160)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1337)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:181)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelUnregistered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:167)
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelUnregistered(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:835)
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:830)
io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Check the memory footprint for the server. I had once a server doing exact the same thing. In that case it was caused by allocating too much heap space. My solution back then was to reduce the ttl for idle-sessions...

Comment: memory and cpu usage are normal no spike on those

Comment: Maybe ulimit? Please post also your pipeline. Do you run those clients from 1 machine?

Comment: In the production environment these clients run from different machines. But in the lab we run these clients from single machine for validation. Both the cases we are getting same problem

Comment: NioEventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(200);
  NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1000);
  ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();

  bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup).channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
    .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
     @Override
     public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
      ch.pipeline().addLast("idleTime", new ReadTimeoutHandler(TIMEOUT, 0, 0));
      ch.pipeline().addLast(new NettyDataHandler());
     }
    });

  bootstrap.bind(host, port).sync();

Comment: You have to much threads for both worker and boss groups. For the bossGroup you may use 1 thread, for workers groups you may use default value (number of cores * 2). Please repeat your test with new numbers and update your port with new result.

Comment: I tried that option but not luck its not even accepting those many connection with ( 16 threads 8 * 2 = 16 ).

Comment: Is this some to do with issue with JDK or kernal level issues ? We are using ubuntu 16 and jdk 1.8.0_152

Comment: I increased the timeout from 3 min to 5 min. READ timeout is not happening but connection is getting drop silently